# Converting char to ascii value

Tags: c++, string, ascii

I know it is stupid question but it does not resolve, and I am googling but that didn't help either. I want to select the sub string from my string and then convert it to ASCII value, but it shows me an error:

```
int a=char(S.substr(i-1,1));
        int b=S.substr(i ,1);
      if (( a== 13) && (b== 10))
        break;
```

this is my error :

> pdusms.cpp:1020: error: invalid cast from type 'std::basic_string' to type 'char'
>                int a=char(S.substr(i-1,1));
>   pdusms.cpp:1021: error: invalid conversion from 'const char*' to 'int' [-fpermissive]
>                int b=S.substr(i ,1).c_str();
>                                           ^
>   How can i do that? how can i change the char to int (show ASCII value)

Comment: Try int b=S.substr(i ,1).c_str();

Comment: I do that. but has error

Comment: @OzairKafray `c_str` returns a pointer. That's not convertible to `char`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The result of `substr` is a string, not a character.
A one-character string is not a character.

Use indexing to get the characters.

You want

```
int a = S[i-1];
int b = S[i];
```

but if you're looking for line delimiters you shouldn't compare to ASCII values - use

```
if (S[i-1] == '\r' && S[i] == '\n')
```

which is portable.